# Using default arguments before positional arguments

Tags: python

I am learning to use positional arguments in python and also trying to see how they work when mixed up with default arguments:-

```
def withPositionalArgs(ae=9,*args):
    print 'ae= ', ae
    print 'args = ', args


a=1
b=2
c=[10,20]

withPositionalArgs(a,b,c)
```

This gives me the output:

```
ae=  1
args =  (2, [10, 20])
```

As you can see, `a` is considered to be a value passed for `ae`, and `b` as well as `c` are considered to be the positional arguments.

So, I am now trying to assign `10` for `ae` while calling `withPositionalArgs`:

```
withPositionalArgs(ae=10,b,c)
```

But, I can not do it. I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

**My question is:**

Am I doing correctly? Is having default argument allowed or a good practice to use before positional arguments in python functions?

Comment: You could call it with `withPositionalArgs(10,b,c)`.

Comment: The "surprising" thing is that calling ...(1,ae=2) throws `TypeError: ...() got multiple values for keyword argument 'ae'`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Python2, you are not allowed to put arguments which have a default value before positional arguments.

The positional arguments must come first, then the arguments with default values (or, when calling the function, the keyword arguments), then `*args`, and then `**kwargs`.

This order is required for both the function definition and for function calls.

In Python3, the order has been relaxed. (For example, `*args` can come before a keyword argument in the function definition.) [See PEP3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

Comment: @unubtu: Is is not allowed both in the definition as well as the function call? Or only at 1 place?

Comment: This is the order one must use for both the definition and the function call. Though, in the function call, you can do things like `foo(c = 1, ae = 3, b = 2)`. That is, the order of the arguments can be jumbled by supplying them keyword arguments.

Comment: It may seem silly to ask, but, Vaughn Cato's comment to my answer allows me to pass the argumenta as required, and python does not give any error. So, shall I modify your answer like:

`In Python, In function calls, you are not allowed to put arguments which have a default parameter before positional arguments. But, you are allowed to do so in function definition` ?

Comment: @GodMan The "default values" part is a red herring.

Comment: Commenting for @bal: When calling the function, keyword arguments come after *args and such to avoid the "Positional argument before keyword argument" error.

Answer (score 4):

I think we should make the distinction of default values vs. passing in arbitrary arguments/key-value pairs. The behaviour without default values is the same:

```
def f(ae,*args, **kwargs):
    print 'ae     = ', ae
    print 'args   = ', args
    print 'kwargs = ', kwargs
```

The way we have written this means that the first argument passed into `f` in the tuple `args`, that is `f(1,2,3,a=1,b=2)` (the sequence goes explicit arguments, *args, **kwargs.) Here: `ae = 1, args = (2,3), kwargs = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}`.

If we try to pass in `f(1,2,3,a=1,ae=3)` we are thrown a `TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'ae'`, since the value of `ae` is attempted to be changed twice.

.

One way around this is to only set `ae` when it is explicitly prescribed, we could (after the def line):

```
def g(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs, kwargs_temp = {"ae": 9}, kwargs
    kwargs.update(kwargs_temp) #merge kwargs into default dictionary
```

and this time `g(1,2,3,a=1,ae=3)` sets `args=(1,2,3), kwargs={a=1,ae=3}`.

*However, I suspect this is not best practice...*

Answer (score 1):

Python3 has relaxed ordering.

Now you can do something like:

```
def withPositionalArgs(*args, ae=9):
    print('ae=', ae)
    print('args =', args)
a=1
b=2
c=[10, 20]
withPositionalArgs(a, b, c, ae=7)
```